# Ionic2 - Cannot see my app in the android emulator

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm not able to see my app in my android emulator.

if I run `cordova build android` I get a successful message:

> :mergeDebugJniLibFolders
>   :transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug :processDebugJavaRes
>   UP-TO-DATE :transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug
>   :validateDebugSigning :packageDebug :zipalignDebug :assembleDebug
>   :cdvBuildDebug
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL
>
> Total time: 23.015 secs Built the following apk(s):
>   C:/Dev/myProject/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk

But as soon as I run `ionic run android` or `ionic emulate android`, the emulator starts, but I cannot see my app there.

What am I missing?

**EDIT**:

Problem is not solved, but this might help:

I receive a few **warnings**:

> **emulator**:
>   WARNING: Increasing RAM size to 1024MB
>
> **emulator**:
>   WARNING: VM heap size set below hardware specified minimum of 48MB
>
> **emulator**:
>   WARNING: Setting VM heap size to 256MB
>
> **libpng warning**: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
>
> **libpng warning**: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile

**EDIT:**

The problem is SOLVED!

I'm using MathJax directive and it seemns like MathJax is not supported by **Chromium**. It is a MathJax issue!

After removing MathJax reference, it worked fine!

Comment: Check the console for the errorrs

Comment: There are no errors, only a few warnings, please see thread update

Comment: It's the problem with ram. Run your app with an emulator that has RAM more than 1 gb